# Error with Zipaligned Application

Tags: android, android-manifest, zipalign

The application works well before zipaligned it.
After signing , the app can't install on my phone or tablets.
I uploaded it to playstore .
It doesn't show error but supported devices shows 0.
Is there any problem ?
Here is manifest.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emapps.easystudy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.6" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portraits" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AwardsGrid"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AwardsGreyGrid"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="screenslide.ScreenSlideActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name=".Notificationmassage" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".StudyingNotification" >
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Setting"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you signing it by command line or using the Android Studio GUI?

Comment: No sir .I used Eclipse.

Comment: So you are building a signed apk with Eclipse and then you're trying to zipalign is that it?

Comment: Yes sir,I right-clicked project => android tools => export signed application package.
That's all sir.

Comment: So that's all, you don't need to zipalign because it was automatic :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the IDE "build signed apk" GUI feature you do not need to zipalign because that last step will be done by the IDE.
If you use the command-line these are the steps: [Signing manually](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually)

[Zipalign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html)

> Caution: zipalign must only be performed after the .apk file has been
>   signed with your private key. If you perform zipalign before signing,
>   then the signing procedure will undo the alignment. Also, do not make
>   alterations to the aligned package. Alterations to the archive, such
>   as renaming or deleting entries, will potentially disrupt the
>   alignment of the modified entry and all later entries. And any files
>   added to an "aligned" archive will not be aligned.